# In Debian (>= 5.0 lenny) how to set scsi_mod's max_luns option?

Tags: linux, storage, scsi, lun

The scsi_mod has this option max_luns which is the "last scsi LUN". How can I view the current setting and change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View current settings:

```
#systool -v -m scsi_mod
```

If not on your Debian system yet, you can install systool with

```
#apt-get install sysfsutils.
```

-If you don't have the file /etc/modprobe.d/local, create it.
-Add the following line:

```
options scsi_mod max_luns=n
```

n is the number you want to have.

Reboot, or remove (modprobe -r) and reinsert (modprobe) the module, and after that check with modinfo.

Comment: The modinfo command does not give the current settings (values), only the description of the parameters ...

Comment: You're right, I overlooked said issue. Maybe try "systool -m scsi_mod"? It's provided in the package "sysfsutils" it seems.

Comment: Yes, that works. The command is "systool -v -m scsi_mod" with the -v option. Please edit you answer so others won't have to read the comments. Thanks for your help! -Alex

Comment: OK, I'm glad it works for you, and changed the answer accordingly.